# Ajax jquery and php problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a french website and it works flawlessly on my localhost it is made with php and javascript and html and mysql.

http://techtionary.comeze.com/game.php

This is the link

the signup works(p.s if you enter any user name and password it will let you in)

Then look at the page game.php

if you look at the source code you will all my ajax requests.

This website was hacked together in one night as an overdue project so do not judge the coding style.

Just please could someone tell me why my ajax post requests are not working.

Comment: Maybe cause you still trying to `load("http://localhost:8888/school/maketable.php")` ?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at it in firebug, your `game.php` file sends a request to `maketable.php` - but it looks for it on the localhost, rather than its location on the server.

Look at the request in firebug:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/school/maketable.php
```

Answer (score 2):

localhost in your code

```
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $("#about").prepend("<div id='message'></div>");
        $("#message").load("http://localhost:8888/school/maketable.php");
    }, 3000);
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $("#points").load("score.php");
```

$("#message").load("http://**localhost:8888**/school/maketable.php");

Comment: oh I realized it my god damn free host is attaching a message at the end of all my stuff and its messing it up.